# How do I access CSS data with selenium using python?

Tags: python, css, django, selenium

Using python (3.4), django (1.9) and selenium (3.0.2), I'm trying to figure out, How can i access CSS code for my automated testing?

**what I'm trying to do:** I want to make sure that the appropriate background images are loading on the appropriate pages. In the past, these have broken when I've changed my project's static settings. I've coded the images into the CSS fairly simply like:

```
background: url('image.jpg')
```

Essentially, I'd like to do something like:

```
css = self.browser.get_css_data('example.css')
self.assertIn('image.jpg', css)
```

I haven't done an exhaustive search, but I don't see anything in the selenium source code webdriver.py that does something like that.

Any ideas of what I could do?

More of my code in case the context helps:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


class UnauthenticatedTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_home_page_loads_correctly(self):
        # The user loads the web page
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertIn('App Name', self.browser.title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check appropriate `css` property of element as below:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="some class name"]')
assert div.value_of_css_property('background-image') == 'url("http://myurl/image.jpg")'
assert div.value_of_css_property('color') == 'rgba(85, 85, 85, 1)'
...
```